# Problema con los espacios en C++

Tags: c++

Al usar un tipo de dato `string`, si le ingreso espacios, no me deja volver a ingresar un dato.

```
struct series{
    string nombre;
    char tematica[15];
    int estreno;
};

struct fans{
    string nombre;
    string direccion;
    string sexo;
    int nacimiento;
    struct series seriesTV[10]; 
}f[10000];

int main(){
        do{
            cout<<"Cuantas serie sigue? "; cin>>n;
        }while( n <= 0 || n > 10);
        cin.ignore();

        while(cont != n){
            cout<<cont+1<<". Digite el nombre de la serie: "; cin>>f[i].seriesTV[cont].nombre;
            cin.ignore();
            cont++;
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No uses cin>> pk solo lee hasta que encuentra un espacio, es una funcion que tiene cin no recuerdo si es getline o alguna parecida

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba usando getline()

Incluye `<string>`

Y reemplaza:

```
cin >> f[i].seriesTV[cont].nombre;
cin.ignore();
```

Por esto:

```
getline(cin, f[i].seriesTV[cont].nombre);
```

Comment: Funciono, gracias

Answer (score -1):

Se utiliza getline.cin para poder almacenar el dato que quieras guardar con el string, además puedes usar el fflush para borrar el buffer.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Además de lo comentado por @Aprendiz, nota que `fflush` no sirve para borrar el buffer sino para volcar su contenido. De ahí que solo tenga sentido en *streams de salida*. De hecho en *streams de entrada* no está aconsejado su uso (en C, en clases de C++ directamente no tienes ese método disponible)